# How can I make a copy of an already created window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

So I am making an xcode application for OS X, and so far things have gone well. However, right now I am at a roadblock. My app is mostly one window, and I need that window to be created multiple times, in the way that apps like Safari, TextEdit, and all those ones have the File>New function. I am new at Xcode, and I was wondering if there was an easy way (hopefully 3-4 lines of code) to do this. If someone could explain that to me that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new OS X project and choose "Create Document Based Application" . This will create a `NSDocument` subclass.

If you want to use Core Data , choose that also. This will create a `NSPersistentDocument` subclass.

[image: New Project Setup]

This will give you the basis of your application with all the functionality you ask for.

Have a look at [Document Based App Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179) and [NSPersistentDocument Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPersistentDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Whatever you do, dont try to bake your own. There lies madness.

The project template sets up the `info.plist` correctly to make this work.

Comment: I did try to make one on my own. :P

Comment: The application that I made... can I copy the stuff from that and paste it into the doc-based app?

Comment: what about the app delegate?

Comment: Re cut and paste. Do anything you want. The project template is a starter kit. The app delegate is the same create and use it if you want one. I think the template has a ref in MainMenu.xib

Comment: Do I make the File's Owner the delegate of my window or the App Delegate?

Comment: The template is setup to make the Document the owner/delegate of its window. The AppDelegate has little or nothing to do with your Document infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever I tell you, it won't involve only "3-4 lines of code," unfortunately.

If you're working from a non-document-based application, you'll want to factor out the code that creates your one window. If you're not using a window controller in concert with your window, you should implement one. Then you can implement an action that will create a new instance of your window controller, and so a new window. Of course, you'll need to add more infrastructure if you're interested in saving information associated with a window to a file.

Which leads me to your other option, which is to create a document-based application. The big advantage here is that, if you're interested in saving the window contents to a file, the infrastructure for doing so is provided. This involves starting over to some extent, but since you've already got the guts of your application working, you'd simply transfer those guts to the document subclass that is provided for you. You'd also need to provide to your project meta information describing the kind of document it is, including the file extension describing it.

Best wishes to you in your endeavors.